# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de actualizar el state de un componente al cambiar una propiedad?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación en reactjs, tengo un componente padre(A) que realiza una petición a un servidor, dicha petición se realiza en el componentDidMount y cambia el state de (A) cuando se completa. El componente padre(A) pasa por props al componente hijo(B) este dato que por defecto es un array vacio en el state de (A). Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo saber desde el componente hijo(B) que las props han cambiado? No sé si la mejor manera es hacer uso del componentWillReceiveProps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si utilizar `componentWillReceiveProps` no te convence podrías utilizar una librería llamada react-watcher, puedes instalarla con ayuda de npm y posteriormente utilizarla de la siguiente forma> [CITO CODIGO DE SU REPOSITORIO DE GITHUB]:
[SU REPOSITORIO & DOCUMENTACION](https://github.com/sborrazas/react-watcher)

```
import connect from 'react-watcher';

class UserDetail extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    return (<div>{id}</div>);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const { watch } = this.props;

    watch('id', (newId) => {
      // New ID assigned, you can use this to dispatch a user fetch action or
      // any other Redux action dispatch or function call.
    });
  }
}

export default connect(UserDetail);
```